# How to effectively remove module created fields?

Tags: 7, entities

During the installation procedure of a module one may create some fields and corresponding instances and attach them to a content type. What is the best practice to clear up what we have created after module uninstallation?

It seems that removing fields created by a module is not yet implemented in D7 (see [`field_modules_uninstalled`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_modules_uninstalled/7) docs.). What would be the best approach then to remove module fields?

- [`field_attach_delete_bundle`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_delete_bundle/7)

**OR**

- [`field_delete_field`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_delete_field/7)

*NOTE:*
the `comment` module removes the field upon uninstallation (see [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.install/function/comment_uninstall/7)).

Comment: `field_delete_field()` + `field_purge_batch()` is all you need; `field_delete_instance()` is called internally from `field_data_field()` anyway

Comment: Thanks for the hyperfast answer! I think you meant `field_delete_field()` and not `field_data_field()`, right?

Comment: Yep I did, you must have seen it before I got the edit in :)

Comment: what would be then the best value for `$batch_size` argument of `field_delete_field` when removing let's say removing 3 fields?

Comment: There's no 'best' value really, it completely depends on the size of data in the fields, the server setup, etc. I normally go for about 100 in custom code, but that figure isn't exactly scientific

Comment: Thanks @Clive ! you just boosted my enthusiasm for developing with drupal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code snippet I usually use to remove fields created by a custom module:

```
if (field_info_field('my_field_name')) {
    field_delete_field('my_field_name');
    field_purge_batch(100);
}
```

Hope this helps